# How to escape backslashes and forward slashes in VIM find/search?

Tags: vim

for example, I want to find and replace, say my original string is "//hello" to "hello".
Actually I'm trying to uncomment lines which I've commented before.

Comment: ``\`` but i recommend using something like that: `https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim`

Comment: In addition to escaping, see `:help pattern-delimiter`.

Answer (score 3):

### substitution

if your pattern contains slashes `/`, e.g. `//hello` you can of course escape them in `s/pat/repl/` command. However, better to pick some another delimiter for your `s` command:

```
:s@//hello@whatever@g
```

In this way, the command is easier to read and understand.

### Search

Say If you want to search `//hello`, you can try a backward search with `?`, then you don't have to escape the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
%s/\/\/hello/hello
```

Comment: Thanks. that was really helpful. It works.

Comment: How to escape "\\hello" ?

Comment: just simply add the backlash:
%s/\\\\hello/hello